# Unnecessary stubbing exception while mocking the object to kafka consumer

Tags: spring-boot, kafka-consumer-api, junit5

I have written a void method for kafka receiver and tried writing the JUNIT but it is throwing the unnecessary stubbing exception

```
 @Component
 public class KafkaReceiver {

    @KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka-receiver-topic}")
    public void receiveTopic(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> consumerRecord) throws 
    Exception {


       JSONObject kafka=new JSONObject(consumerRecord.value().toString());

       }
    }
```

The JUNIT test case I have return below is throwing the stubbing exception

```
   @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
   public class KafkaReceiverTest {


   @Test
   public void receiveTopicTest() throws Exception {
    KafkaReceiver producer = Mockito.mock(KafkaReceiver.class);


      JSONObject expected = new JSONObject(); 
                expected.put("value","value");    

      ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record = new ConsumerRecord<>("topic", 0, 123L, 
                                                           "key",expected); 
      JSONObject exp = new JSONObject(record.value().toString());


      doNothing().when(producer).receiveTopic(record);
      assertEquals(expected.get("value"), exp.get("value"));
     }
     }
```